# Is there a possible way to set the value of child nodes unique from other child node in firebase realtime database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So my project is to let a created user sign in as a hotel chain administrator who is able to create a hotel under the hotel chain. Regarding the picture, the admin of Hampton is able to create hotels with names and amount of rooms and its location in the integer grid form.

However, I can't figure out a way to set the child nodes grid_X and grid_Y unique from every other child nodes.

Let's say the admin of Hampton wants to create a new hotel with grid_X: "95" and grid_Y: "-30", it should not be allowed. How do you set the rules? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: grid_X and grid_Y are generated in the code? Or are they provided as an input by the administrator?

Comment: They are generated using database.ref and set function when the user signed in as an administrator then submit the value through html website.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a separate node of 'used grids' and check it when you want to add a new hotel.

Update based on your comment:

In my view the rules are to control database access security, not to manage the data on the database. That is what your app code is for. So, before you add a new hotel you read the 'usedGrids' node to see if the grid value exists. If it doesn't, you add the hotel and at the same time you add that new hotel's grid values to the 'usedGrids' node.

Comment: Thank you but how do you check it when I want to add a new hotel? using the rules setting in realtime database console or javascript?